# How flutter ccavenue configuration error?

Tags: flutter, dart, ccavenue

i need ccavenue payment gateway integration flutter. i followed this official link https://pub.dev/packages/cc_avenue . but it shows PlatformException.

i followed this official link https://pub.dev/packages/cc_avenue . but it shows PlatformException.

E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.ccaven/com.avinash.gotluru.cc_avenue.Framework.WebViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared ?
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2197)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1839)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5471)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5429)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5927)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5894)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at com.avinash.gotluru.cc_avenue.CcAvenuePlugin.cCAvenueInIt(CcAvenuePlugin.java:78)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at com.avinash.gotluru.cc_avenue.CcAvenuePlugin.onMethodCall(CcAvenuePlugin.java:60)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#cc_avenue(25116):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

Answer (score 0):

You try this code

your AndroidManifest.xml  add this line

and  see here how to implement this
https://github.com/avinash-gotluru/cc_avenue/blob/main/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

if  you add this code then flutter clean, flutter pub get, and close your framework and again open and flutter clean and flutter pub get  and  then delete the app your phone and rebuild this app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).